# How to mount Sony FR7 to Wall

Tags: video-recording, camera, broadcasting, sony, grip

I'm trying to mount this PTZ camera to the side of the wall not the ceiling or on a pole.
On the side of the wall is there a good way of doing this?

I've looked at [Sony's Documentation](https://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/2240/v1/en/contents/TP1000669517.html) and they only offer a guide on Upright in a High location or a Ceiling mount solution

[image: Sony FR7 Drawing]